# Highcharts 2.4.5 in Extjs 6.2.0 ( Chp-5 Example of highcharts cookbook)

Tags: javascript, extjs, highcharts

Example taken from high charts cookbook (PACK T Books)
following code is running

```
launch : function() {       
    var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{    
        layout: 'border',    
        items: [{
                region: 'west',
                width: 200,
                title: 'test',
                html: 'testing'
        }]
    });
}
```

As soon as I insert the following code for high charts nothing gets displayed in the browser (app.js)

```
Ext.require('Ext.container.Viewport');
Ext.Loader.setPath('Chart', '../resources/Chart');
Ext.require('Chart.ux.Highcharts');
Ext.require('Chart.ux.Highcharts.Serie');
Ext.require('Chart.ux.Highcharts.LineSerie');
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {

    var chart = Ext.create('Chart.ux.Highcharts',{
        region: 'center',
        id: 'chart',
        initAnimAfterLoad: false,
        chartConfig: {
          chart: {
            type: 'line',
            showAxes: true
        },
        title: {
            text: 'a simple graph'
        }
       }
    });

    var viewport = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport',{
        layout: 'border',
        items: [{
                region: 'west',
                width: 200,
                title: 'test',
                html: 'testing'
        },chart]
    });

    chart.addSeries([{
                name: 'Series #1',
                data: [1,2,3]
    }],false);
}
});
```

/var/www/html/example/index.html includes

```
ext-all.css | ext-all.js | jquery.dev.js |jquery-1.11.3.min.js |highcharts.src.js |highcharts-more.src.js |
```

Please suggest some solution or any alternative.

Comment: See the description of chart.addSeries() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Chart.addSeries It takes an object, not an array of objects.

Comment: please, give an example. Actually I am new to Ext JS.

Comment: An example of using addSeries() is available in the link I pasted. You typed addSeries([{ ... }]) but you should addSeries({ ... })